# picture.insert with hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, image, hyperlink, insert

I have a link to a picture that is automatically generated. Now I tried to let a button insert the actual image to excel, but nothing seems to work.

Debugger highlights the "ActiveSheet" part with error codes 4xx or 1xxx when I play around with similar alternatives - ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert.
No solution on google so far.

```
Sub Insert_Picture()

  Dim url
  Dim pic As String 'file path of pic
  Dim myPicture As Picture 'embedded pic

  url = Range("Tabelle1!A1").Value
  pic = "url"

  Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pic = "url"
Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)
```

I believe that you will find that `"url"` is not a valid URL.  Did you mean to write `pic = url` instead?

(You could also use `Dir` to check if the file exists before you try to insert it)